# Use a 2.5" LCD in a Blaupunkt Dashcam for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-zero, display, lcd

and thank you for reading my topic. I recently bought a "2.5" LCD HD Dashcam" from the Blaupunkt brand (BPDV122), although I am aware they have just used this design from another company.
https://www.blaupunkt.com/us/nc/products/in-vehicle-entertainment/cameras/products/single/14773/

I took it apart in hopes of using its LCD screen for another project. I couldn't find any specifications online, however I did find a lot of links to Remont-Aud. Many users there have disassembled similar models or the same model.
https://remont-aud.net/dump/gps_navigatory_videoregistratory/prochee/no_name_no_name_shassi_main_board_js_c007m_main_v1_2/296-1-0-51507
https://remont-aud.net/dump/gps_navigatory_videoregistratory/prochee/no_name_no_name_shassi_main_board_l100d_main_v03_20171115/296-1-0-68178
https://remont-aud.net/dump/gps_navigatory_videoregistratory/prochee/no_name_hd_dvr_hd_portable_dvr_with_2_5tft_lcd_screen_shassi_main_board_shassi_main_board_hxx101_mian_20160814v13b/296-1-0-44206

The Dashcam comes in two boards connected with a 24-pin AWM 20624 ribbon cable. The first board has the camera, LED lights, SD card reader, USB port, speaker, power on button, and record/select button. The second board has the 2.5" LCD screen and four buttons (Menu, up, down, and mode).

This video shows the teardown of one of these models: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKeAGffMmJI

I wish to use the LCD screen from this Dashcam with a Raspberry Pi Zero..the quality of the camera aspect wasn't important to me. If anyone here can help me, it would be very appreciated.

Board markings
On the first board: JS-C007M MAIN_V1.2 2016-06-08
On the second board: 20160507 and JS-C007M-LCD-V1.2
On the LCD flex cable: H9341, SJ24N-3670F, and HXY

Comment: you need to locate the LCD controller chip ... google the markings on the chip

Comment: I looked up a couple chips on the first board; voltage regulators, mosfets, chips for the charging circuit, and three larger chips. There was only one chip on the second board, another mosfet. The largest chip on the first board reads "24CC MQNK 173.1 1634". Googling that and those parts brought up nothing. The second largest read "MK 25Q80BVNIG 1645" which came up with the Winbond W25Q80BV. It seems to be "8-mbit serial flash memory with dual/quad SPI". I've seen some LCD displays marketed as being usable with SPI, so I assume this chip handles the display.